# Riot custom tag not loading (hello world example)

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I have the most basic possible custom tag, but it's not mounting. Also if I use `riot.mount('*')` I get this error in riot.min.js

```
Uncaught SyntaxError:
Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty.
```

Compiled Tag

```
riot.tag('test', '<div>Hello world!</div>', function(opts) {
});
```

Index file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <test></test>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/riot/2.2/riot.min.js"></script>
  <script src="tags/test.js" type="riot/tag"></script>
  <script>riot.mount('test')</script>
  <!-- <script>riot.mount('*')</script> throws error -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh was mixing the pre-compiled and browser compiled syntax. After removing `type="riot/tag"` from my tag reference it mounted correctly.